# Amazon Glacier: How to debug

Tags: amazon-glacier

I creating a client for Amazon Glacier. Debugging it is hell. Downloading takes 4 hours. Are there any tools for debugging Amazon Glacier?

Comment: Did you try the Aws API simulator?

Comment: @alexandresaiz No, I didn't. I do not found simulator for Glacier. Could you give me a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Use [AWS CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/ru/cli/).
2. Use next scenario:

   - Create a lot of jobs.
   - Save jobs IDs.
   - Waiting jobs completation (4 hours).
   - Debug all you like with using saved jobs IDs.